# GitHub links in Sphinx docs

Tags: github, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Here's an example Sphinx doc:
https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/v0.13.2/docs/release_notes/v0.13.2.rst

I'd like commit SHA's, issue numbers, and @mentions to be hyperlinked. Anyway to do that automatically?

Comment: You could perhaps try the [`sphinx.ext.extlinks`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/extlinks.html) extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest checking out the Sphinx Extension library at http://sphinxext-survey.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog-version-control.html.

Specifically, I believe these two extensions may provide you at least some of the support you're looking for (sans the @mentions).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-github

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-issuetracker