# Incremental links in RST

Tags: hyperlink, restructuredtext

I have a .rst file where I keep the changes of my project:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giampaolo/psutil/master/HISTORY.rst

I mark every issue number as `number_` (e.g. `1512_`) and at the bottom of the page I add the hyperlink as:

```
.. _1512: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/
```

This is not maintainable (file gets too big, issue numbers grow exponentially). Is there a way to automate that so that I avoid the repetitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub links in Sphinx docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415570/github-links-in-sphinx-docs)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a custom restructuredText "interpreted text role".  I mention this not because I expect you to know what that is but to provide some key words to search on if this answer doesn't get you all the way to your goal.

If you're using Sphinx, then you can probably just use the included `extlinks` [extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html)

Another option might be to use the [issuetracker extension](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-issuetracker/).

Either of these should allow you to write something like (using an example from you file referenced above):

```
- :issue:`1529`: [AIX] compilation error on AIX 7.2 due to 32 vs 64 bit differences.
  (patch by Arnon Yaari)
```

If that doesn't work for you use case, you can also write your own role.  Essentially this means writing you own Python function and registering it with docutils to produce the output you want.  There's some documentation on how to create your own roles [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-roles.html)

You might also be able to modify another similar extension, e.g. the `traclinks` extension ([here](https://github.com/thewtex/sphinx-contrib/tree/master/traclinks) or [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/)).